# Can I move components within a flex with space-between?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using Material UI and currently I'm trying to move my group of radio buttons leftwards
from:
[image]

to:
[image]

And this is a snippet of my code:

```
<Grid item xs={6}>
    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
        <Typography variant="h2" sx={{ alignSelf: "center" }}>Function</Typography>
        <FormControl>
            <RadioGroup
               row
               value={selectedFunction}
               onChange={handleSelectedFunction}
            >
                <FormControlLabel value={functions[0]} control={<Radio />} label="T" />
                <FormControlLabel value={functions[1]} control={<Radio />} label="S" />
            </RadioGroup>
        </FormControl>
    </Box>
</Grid>
```

What can I do to my code to enable the FormControl to move leftwards?

Comment: Just remove the `justifyContent` - the default is `flexStart` which will line the items up as described. You can use a `Stack` instead of a `Box` if you want to have a gap between the components, too.

Comment: Thanks! Can I also make it responsive to the screen dimensions?

Comment: Yep - https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#responsive-values